# How can I test the value of ASP.NET Controller response status codes without using their literal number?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I noticed that ASP.NET Core controllers, when returning status codes for requests, can return `NotFound()` for a 404, or `Ok()` for a 200, which are `StatusCodeResult` objects. Here's an example controller function that does so:

```
public ActionResult<MyItem> GetItemById(int ItemId) {
    var item = _service.GetItemById(ItemId);
    if (item is null) {
        return NotFound();
    }
    return item;
}
```

When I write a unit test for this controller's `GetItemById` function, and I want to test if it returns a 404 when there is no item with that `ItemId`, I currently write the following unit test (I'm using xUnit in this example):

```
[Fact]
public void TestGetItemByIdNotFound() {
    var response = controller.GetItemById(1); // no item with ItemId 1
    var result = Assert.IsType<NotFoundResult>(response);
    Assert.Equal(404,result!.StatusCode);
}
```

In my test, I'm comparing the integer 404 with the status code of the result. I would prefer to reference something similar to `NotFound()` instead of a number in my test so that I don't have to memorize the status code for every `StatusCodeResult` that my controller will return, and just have something with similar syntax in my assertion. Is there a way to do so?

So far, I've just made an enumerator of different status codes and their returns, then referenced those in my test:

```
enum StatusCodes {
    Ok = 200,
    NotFound = 404,
    ...
}

...

Assert.Equal((int)StatusCodes.NotFound, result!.StatusCode)
```

But I'm curious if there's a cleaner way that leaves me without having to enumerate every possible status code.

Comment: There already is [System.Net.HttpStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-7.0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if the Item is not found. For this case, the unit test just checks if the return type is `NotFoundResult`, you don't need to manually check for the status code because we already check the type which ensures that status code will be 404.

moreover like @Martin mention status codes already defined in [System.Net.HttpStatusCode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpstatuscode?view=net-7.0)